# Array of objects not getting deleted

Tags: c++, allocation

I just wanted to test something out and encountered a strange issue...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class C
{
    public:
        ~C()
        {
            cout<<"bye world!"<<endl;
        }
        void foo()
        {
            cout<<"I'm alive"<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    C* thing = new C;
    delete thing; // destructor called
    thing->foo(); // it's alive!!!
}
```

Running this code I get the following results:
"Bye world!"
"I'm alive!"
shouldn't thing->foo() result in an exception since thing was deleted one line before?

Comment: *`it's alive!!!`* - No, you just wrote code with undefined behavior. Too bad for you, it ended up "working".

Comment: "_shouldn't thing->foo() result in an exception since thing was deleted one line before?_" Who told you that it should?